# tar (child): prometheus-2.8.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

While building from a Dockerfile, I get an error as

```
tar (child): prometheus-2.8.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
```

But I did `RUN ls -lsa` before `tar` command, and the output is

```
Step 7/20 : RUN ls -lsa
 ---> Running in 6d417da0b003
total 37928
    8 drwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     4096 Jun 10 14:08 .
    8 drwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     4096 Jun 10 14:08 ..
    4 -rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root        0 Jun 10 14:08 .dockerenv
    8 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 May  6 00:00 bin
    8 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 Mar 28 09:12 boot
    0 drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root      340 Jun 10 14:08 dev
    8 drwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     4096 Jun 10 14:08 etc
    8 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 Mar 28 09:12 home
    8 drwxr-xr-x.  8 root root     4096 May  6 00:00 lib
    8 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 May  6 00:00 lib64
    8 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 May  6 00:00 media
    8 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 May  6 00:00 mnt
    8 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 May  6 00:00 opt
    0 dr-xr-xr-x. 98 root root        0 Jun 10 14:08 proc
37780 -rw-r--r--.  1 root root 38682609 Mar 28 19:19 prometheus-2.8.1.linux-arm64.tar.gz
    8 drwx------.  1 root root     4096 Jun 10 14:08 root
    8 drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     4096 May  6 00:00 run
    8 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 May  6 00:00 sbin
    8 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     4096 May  6 00:00 srv
    0 dr-xr-xr-x. 13 root root        0 Jun 10 14:06 sys
    8 drwxrwxrwt.  1 root root     4096 Jun 10 14:08 tmp
    8 drwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     4096 May  6 00:00 usr
    8 drwxr-xr-x.  1 root root     4096 May  6 00:00 var
Removing intermediate container 6d417da0b003
 ---> 3c7f16cdd4ad
```

So the tar file is already present in the current directory.
What's wrong with the `tar` command?

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM debian:9

ARG PROMETHEUS_VERSION=2.8.1
ARG ARCH=arm64


RUN apt-get update 
RUN  apt-get install -y wget 
RUN  wget https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases/download/v${PROMETHEUS_VERSION}/prometheus-${PROMETHEUS_VERSION}.linux-arm64.tar.gz 
RUN ls -lsa
RUN echo "$PWD"
RUN tar jxvf  prometheus-${PROMETHEUS_VERSION}.linux-${ARCH}.tar.gz -C prometheus-${PROMETHEUS_VERSION}.linux-arm64/prometheus 
RUN ls -lsa
RUN cp prometheus-$PROMETHEUS_VERSION.linux-arm64/prometheus .
```

Please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

When you are extracting the tar file you use this name:

> prometheus-2.8.1.linux-**amd64**.tar.gz

But you are downloading different file:

> prometheus-2.8.1.linux-**arm64**.tar.gz

`amd64 -> arm64`

This is happening because sometimes you are using the variable `$ARCH` and sometimes you use `arm64`.
Replace everywhere you use `arm64` with the variable `$ARCH`. And if you want to use a different arch, you can pass this flag to `docker build`:

> --build-arg arch=arm64

Answer (score 0):

Let try:

`RUN tar jxvf  prometheus-${PROMETHEUS_VERSION}.linux-${ARCH}.tar.gz -C prometheus-${PROMETHEUS_VERSION}.linux-arm64/prometheus`

Instead of:

`RUN mkdir -p prometheus-${PROMETHEUS_VERSION}.linux-arm64/prometheus && RUN tar -zxf prometheus-${PROMETHEUS_VERSION}.linux-${ARCH}.tar.gz -C prometheus-${PROMETHEUS_VERSION}.linux-arm64/prometheus --strip-components=1`

The flag `--strip-components`: 
`--strip-components=NUMBER   strip NUMBER leading components from file`